# Instantiated List as valid IList Argument

Tags: vb.net

This is by no means a serious issue for me as I have worked around it, but I am more inquisitive to the difference and why one compiles and another won't. Take a look at the following examples:

This builds.

```
Sub Foo()

   Dim someL as IList(Of Integer) = New List(Of Integer)
   Bar(someL)

End Sub

Sub Bar(ByRef argSomeL as IList(Of Integer))
'do stuff
End Sub
```

Notice that bar's argument is that of an IList. And SomeL is an actual List(Of Int)
The following will not compile:

```
Sub Foo()

   Dim someL as New List(Of Integer)
   Bar(someL)

End Sub

Sub Bar(ByRef argSomeL as IList(Of Integer))
   'do stuff
End Sub
```

Are they not both (Foo()) calling Bar with an argument of a List not an IList?

Comment: Your second example should also compile and work (besides the missing `)` at the end of `Sub Bar(argSomeL as IList(Of Integer)`). Which error do you get?

Comment: The only situation that this is the case is if the argument is being passed in ByRef.

Comment: I typed in the code here, not copied from VS, my bad. Added the missing parenthesis / ByRef.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ByRef extends the SCOPE of the called function to include callee function's variable for the byref parameter -- ie it allows changing the VARIABLE of the callee.

It would be almost entirely superfluous if VB allowed multiple return values.

```
Dim local1 , local2 as int
(local1, local2) = Bar(local2)
```

This also hints at a solution for your example - don't use byRef and a sub, use byval and a function.

```
Function Bar(ByVal foo As IList(of Integer)) As IList(of Integer)
   Return foo
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because when it's passed in ByRef the parameter has to be able to take whatever the function wants to put into it.
In your first example if the function decides to do something like...

```
argSomeL = New MikesListOfInts() ' Assuming MikesListOfInts implements IList(Of Integer)
```

it can, and the variable someL in the calling function can be set to an MikesListOfInts since it is of type IList.

However, in your second example, .Net will have no clue on how to turn a MikesListOfInts into a List(of Int).